# Return an Entity object from a controller not managed by spring data-rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a `Parent` entity along with it's `ParentRepository` as follows

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "Parent", path = "parent")
public interface ParentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Parent, Long>{

}
```

`GET: /parent/10` returns this output as expected

```
{
  "pid" : 10,
  "parentName" : "Parent 10",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:1111/app/api/v2/parent/10"
    },
    "parent" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:1111/app/api/v2/parent/10"
    },
    "children" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:1111/app/api/v2/parent/10/children"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a `@RestController` method as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdummy")
    public Parent getdummy() {
        //Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        //Parent parent=(Parent)session.get(Parent.class, new Long(10));
        Parent parent=new Parent();
        parent.setPid(new Long(1111));
        parent.setParentName("Parent name");
        Child c1=new Child();
        c1.setChildName("C1");
        c1.setChildKey(new Long(1234));
        c1.setParent(parent);
        Child c2=new Child();
        c2.setChildName("C2");
        c2.setChildKey(new Long(1235));
        c2.setParent(parent);
        List<Child> children=new ArrayList<>();
        children.add(c1);
        children.add(c2);
        parent.setChildren(children);

        return parent;

    }
```

This method is expected to return a JSON as below:

```
{
    "pid": 1111,
    "parentName": "Parent name",
    "children": [{
        "childKey": 1234,
        "childName": "C1",
        "grandChildren": null
    },
    {
        "childKey": 1235,
        "childName": "C2",
        "grandChildren": null
    }]
}
```

But what I get is this

```
{
  "pid" : 1111,
  "parentName" : "Parent name"
}
```

The only way I was able to make it work with spring data rest was by converting the`Parent` object to `String` using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`

I tried excluding spring data-rest from my POM, and it gives the expected output. How do I exclude a particular Controller/Method from the data-rest interceptor?

[Source here](https://bitbucket.org/rkysh/spring-repo/src)

Comment: Did you try return ``parent`` using ``parent=parentRepository.save(parent);``

Comment: I don't want to save it. Also I tried returning an instance from Hibernate (the commented lines), even that returns the unexpected json. On debugging I could see that hibernate has fetched all the Child and Grandchild objects. But the controller returns the wrong json

Comment: Have you tried annotating your controller method with `@ResponseBody` ?

Comment: You don't need that when you are using `@RestController`. It works without data-rest, so i don't think the issue is with `@ResponseBody`.